# Avoiding overlapping image and text in a custom TextBox?

Tags: winforms, user-controls

I've derived a new control from a System.Windows.Forms.TextBox which displays an image on its client area, as you can see from the following image:

[image: UnitTextBox]

Here is the code:

```
public partial class UnitTextBox: TextBox {
    public UnitTextBox() {
        TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        InitializeComponent();
        Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    }
}
```

When I add some characters the text scrolls to the left and goes below the image. Is there a way to pad the text area?

Comment: It's unclear how you are displaying an image in the client area to begin with since you haven't posted any code.

Answer (score 2):

I did a similar thing once. The easiest way to do this is to create a UserControl like BradRem proposed, then put a borderless TextBox in a Panel with the same background color as the TextBox. To the left in this panel you put your icon. As a complete UserControl this now behaves as a TextBox with a reserved area to the left with an icon in it.

**Update:**

I had to test this for myself and created a UserControl like I said. In addition I added a Paint event to the container Panel that draws the border with the same color as the TextBox:

```
    public partial class UCTextBoxWithLabel : UserControl {
        public UCTextBoxWithLabel() {
            InitializeComponent();

            pnlTextBoxWithImage.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(pnlTextBoxWithImage_Paint);
        }

        void pnlTextBoxWithImage_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs pea) {
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(pea.Graphics, pea.ClipRectangle, Color.FromArgb(0x7f, 0x9d, 0xb9), ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
        }
    }
```

...and it looks pretty much exactly like the result you want:

[image: Screenshot of program]

Comment: Hi Pedery and @BradRem, I tried to inherit from a UserControl but the control border is different from a normal Fixed3D border of a TextBox. I've a lot of other TextBoxes on the forms and mixing the two border styles is not good.

Comment: You just set the border property of the Panel, like I outlined in my solution above.

Comment: I've set the BorderStyle property to Fixed3D or FixedSingle but it looks different from the border of a normal TextBox, as you can see [here](http://www.b2s.it/temp/Immagine1.png) and [here](http://www.b2s.it/temp/Immagine2.png). Then I tried also embedding the picturebox and the textbox onto a new textbox. In this way the border looks ok when the control is not selected, but when it gets the focus the border do not change its color!

Comment: @stenio, do what Pedery said to do but instead of using a panel, use another TextBox with a Fixed3D border and TabStop set to false. If you position your borderless icon and actual textbox a few pixels in, you will get the affect you're looking for.

Comment: I added my solution to your problem above.

Comment: Yep, what BradRem wrote will also work. Yet it's a bit crude since you have to make sure beyond the shadow of a doubt that the user cannot place focus in the bottom most TextBox. Yet it will save you the "hassle" of drawing the border manually.

Comment: @BradRem, Yes I did in this way. The only problem is the absence of the color change of the border when the control gets the focus. The outer control cannot get the focus and so the border remains "unfocused". It would be useful to have a function to draw the border in focused style when the inner control gets the focus.

Comment: If you're drawing manually, you might as well do it properly like I showed you. If you want the 3D-look, you can paint using ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(), and it's easy to check whether your control has focus.

Comment: Finally I have used the solution with two overlapping textboxes in order to preserve the visual style of the original textbox. Thanks @BradRem and Pedery.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like with what you're trying to do would be easier for you if you made it a UserControl:

[MSDN - Inherit from the UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00ctb4z0.aspx)

Generally, in Visual Studio you "Add" to your project a new "User Control" which looks nearly like a Form. Add to it a panel or PictureBox for your image and then to the right of it add your TextBox. Size the form down to just fit your controls.  Create some Properties to expose the TextBox's Text property and possibly a property to set the image and then compile. Once you compile, your User Control will appear in your Toolbox as if it were any other control.